# NoClassDefFoundError when running r.js on MacOS X

Tags: java, javascript, macos, requirejs, r.js

I'm trying to run the r.js (require.js optimizer) with this block of commands in my Mac terminal. Interestingly, I get an error by just typing java in the terminal. Keep in mind the Mac has Java installed by default.

```
java \          
-classpath \      //maybe classpath is wrong?
js.jar \      //this is a java file required for the optimization
org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main \ //specific part of the .jar file is called
r.js \   //this is the optimizer's js file
-o \       //telling it to optimize
build.js   //this is the config file
```

build.js:

```
({
    baseUrl: '../public/sites/triathlonresearchnnb/js',                  //where to look in
    mainConfigFile: '../public/sites/triathlonresearchnnb/js/main.js',   //dir of our main file
    name: '../Scripts/main',                //which one
    out: '../public/sites/triathlonresearchnnb/js/scripts.min.js',       //final concatenated and minified product path
})
```

Java error in the command line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: Looking at the error message, it seems that either part of the error message is missing (the name of the class that couldn't be found), or something is telling Java to load a class without name. `org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main` was certainly found, because if it wasn't, the error message would be `Error: Could not find or load main class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main`.

Comment: We can also tell that the class that was not found is loaded implicitly, not with `Class.forName` - else it would be `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Are you able to do the same steps on a Windows or Linux machine? If so, please do it and report if you get the same error. Please also provide where you've downloaded the `js.jar` and `r.js`.

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js#os-xlinuxunix-1) suggests both Rhino **and** the Closure Compiler in your classpath:

```
$ java -classpath path/to/rhino/js.jar:path/to/closure/compiler.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main r.js -o path/to/buildconfig.js
```

Your question is only showing a classpath for something which may be Rhino. The Closure Compiler is available [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/lib/closure/compiler.jar?raw=true).

Comment: I really don't know what to make out of your answer. It throws an error yet again.